# Make a copy of a file and give it a different name mac terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, cp

Mac.

I'm in a directory `dogs/scripts/cats`.

Within this directory there is a file `bla.txt`.

I would like to make a copy of `bla.txt` called `bla2.txt` and keep it in the same directory.

How do I do that?

```
cp bla.txt dogs/scripts/cats
```

> 'bla.txt' and `dogs/scripts/cats/bla.txt' are the same file

Comment: `cp bla.txt bla2.txt`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`cp` can get a name of a target file:

```
cp bla.txt ./bla2.txt
```

Or even simpler, as Mark noted:

```
cp bla.txt bla2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, knew it had to be something simple but google searches kept telling me how to copy the file to a new directory with the file having the same name

Comment: I understand that `./` means *"the current directory"* but what's the logic of introducing that here, when `cp bla.txt bla2.txt` does exactly the same thing but more simply?

Comment: Tell me about it :-) :-)